# Deleting Records in a dbGrid Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado, dbgrid

I am looking for a solution to a rather serious problem I'm facing;
I want to delete a record in a dbGrid but when I click on my coded button and confirm 'Delete', I find no immediate results. In order to find the result of the deleted record, I have to close the program and re-run it. Only then do I see that the record is deleted.

My coding looks basically as follows

```
procedure TfrmPunte.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
sName, sLeerderNo : string;
begin
with dmPunte do
  begin
    sLeerderNo := tblLeerder['LeerderNr'];
    sName := tblLeerder['NaamVan']; 
    if MessageDlg('Is jy seker dat jy ' + sName + ' met Leerder Nommer ' + sLeerderNo + ' wil wis van die rekords? Neem kennis dat al die rekords van sy/haar aktiwiteite ook uitgevee sal word!', mtWarning, [mbOk, mbCancel],0) = mrOK then
      tblDeelname.Open;
      tblDeelname.First; 
       while NOT tblDeelname.Eof do
        begin
          if tblDeelname['LeerderNr'] = sLeerderNo then
          tblDeelname.Delete;
          tblDeelname.Next;
        end;
      tblLeerder.Delete;
      tblLeerder.Active := False;
      tblLeerder.Active := True;
  end;
end;
```

I am using an ADO table connected to ADO connection connected to an ACCESS database. I do appologize, some variable names are in Afrikaans.
What should I do?

Comment: The record that was supposed to be deleted is still shown in the db Grid, I am using an ADO Table with ADO connection.

Comment: On a quick view: next after delete will skip one record after deleting a record. You have to insert else before next

Comment: I asume that "tblLeerder" and "tblDeelname" are both TADODataSet and in the grid is shown the content of  "tblDeelname". Than you have to include actice:=false and active:=true after  tblDeelname.delete. If tblLeerder is connected to the DBGrid thas the question is what do you want to see?

Comment: tblLeerder and tblDeelname are both ADOTable.

Comment: Only thing I can think of, is that your dbgrid is connected to other dataset

Comment: Oh, Please stop down-voting this question. He is a very new member. Is this how you will say welcome? Please be helpful instead.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `begin - end` pair around the lines after the `if MessageDlg() then` line.

Comment: @ChristineRoss thank you very much! Yes I am very new to this website and I come here only to look for a sollution to this coding problem that I am still unable to fix. This is all for a Practical Assesment Task / Project for school. Thank you for everyones _**KIND**_ advice so far and also for those who treat me like a piece of ****.

Comment: If your problem is still open, I would recommend that you publish the whole (really the whole) project e.g. in google drive and publish the link here. From what we discussed it should work. So the problem lies in an area that is out of your focus

Answer (score 0):

`Table.refresh` does not work in every environment. The safe way is

```
Table.Active := False; 
Table.Active := True;
```

Be aware of a problem that the actual dataset is lost. You can store it and get back locate.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Christine, I tried it but unfortunately it still does not work....

Comment: Than you have to be more specific. Please show us the complete code (what type is table?). What means delete in dbgrid? I would understand: delete record in dataset and refresh dbgrid???

Comment: I added my code in the answers Christine, Thank you very much for all your help so far.

Comment: @David Heffernan good question; maybe I was to quick from my experience. To be sure it should be something like: DBGrid.DataSource.Dataset.active:=false

Comment: @ChristineRoss - I tired this but still it does not work as it should! For some reason, the dbGrid only shows the changes you've made (ex Deleting a record) after you've closed the program and then run it again. What else do you suggest I do??

Comment: @ChristineRoss What does " the actual dataset is lost." mean?  Also "You can store it and get back locate[sic]."  Do you mean "save it locally using SaveToFile and .LoadFromFile" or what?

Comment: Sorry, for the unclear comment. I use following code: ID:=SGDS.DataSet['MG_ID'];
SGDS.DataSet.Active:=false;
SGDS.DataSet.Active:=true;
if SGDS.DataSet.Locate('MG_ID',ID,[]) then
    ;
Where MG_ID is the primary key. The point is that the actual marked pointer is lost. The grid points to any other record. So you have to store which record is the actual record and after active:=true you have to come back by locate. You also can use TBookmark.